Suppress warning messages when lightgbm is used in optuna?
I want to suppress the warnings, however I am unable to do so.
This issue is happening only when I am using a custom objective function instead of a regular one. I have tried multiple things to resolve the issue this like importing the warnings module and trying to suppress externally that didn't work. I also tried, setting both verbose and verbosity but nothing has worked.
Any help would be appreciated.
def hinge_loss():
    
    def hinge_loss_lgb(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = 2 * y_true - 1  # Convert 0, 1 to -1, 1
        margin = y_true * y_pred
        grad = np.where(margin < 1, -y_true, 0)
        hess = np.where(margin < 1, 1, 0)
        return grad, hess

    return hinge_loss_lgb

max_evals = 25

fixed_params_gbm2 = {
        'objective': hinge_loss(),  
        'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
        'colsample_bytree': 0.5,
        'subsample': 0.5,
    }
    
    def gbm_cl_bo2(params):
        stratified_kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
        accuracy_scores = []
        
        for train_index, val_index in stratified_kfold.split(train_features, train_labels):
            X_train, X_val = train_features[train_index], train_features[val_index]
            y_train, y_val = train_labels[train_index], train_labels[val_index]
            
            model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(fixed_params_gbm2, params, verbosity=-1)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            
            y_preds = loss.sigmoid(model.predict(X_val))
            y_pred_binary = (y_preds > 0.5).astype(int)  # Convert to binary predictions
            
            accuracy = accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred_binary)
            accuracy_scores.append(accuracy)
        
        return np.mean(accuracy_scores)
    
    # The objective function for Optuna
    def objective(trial):
        space_lr = {
            'max_depth': trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 1, 3),
            'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.0001, 0.3, step=0.0001),
            'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int("n_estimators", 50, 1000, step=50),
            'min_split_gain': trial.suggest_float('min_split_gain', 0, 1, step=0.00001),
            'min_child_samples': trial.suggest_int('min_child_samples', 0, 10000),
        }
        
        return gbm_cl_bo2(space_lr)
    
    # Create the Optuna study object and optimize
    studyObject1 = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize', sampler=TPESampler())
    studyObject1.optimize(objective, n_trials=max_evals, n_jobs=6)


OUTPUT
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[I 2024-08-28 01:11:53,083] Trial 24 finished with value: 0.507014349610781 and parameters: {'max_depth': 2, 'learning_rate': 0.2655, 'n_estimators': 1000, 'min_split_gain': 0.74372, 'min_child_samples': 3400}. Best is trial 15 with value: 0.5076209963565378.
